# href in caption of listings

Tags: hyperref, listings, captions

since copy-pasting text from PDFs, escpecially source code, can be problematic, I'd like to provide a reference to the acutal file from within the listings caption. This does work fine, except for the \lstlistoflistings that now also references that file instead of the section within the PDF showing that lisiting.

Is there a way to restore the default behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \lstlistoflistings

  \lstinputlisting[
    caption = {\href{run:./hello_world.py}{hello\_world.py}},
    language = python,
  ]{hello_world.py}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
caption = {[\texttt{hello\_world.py}]\href{run:./hello_world.py}{hello\_world.py}},
```

`caption` can define a "short" entry for the list of listings.

```
caption={[short]long}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Herbert’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449625/69818) suggests the solution I too would recommend, in that it doesn’t mess up the `.lol` file with useless junk.  However, another posibility is to “sterilize” locally the `\href` command: this has the advantage, on the other hand, that it requires to modify the source files in a single place only.

In general, the simple redefinition used in the following MWE (the one that uses `\renewcommand`) should suffice, but don’t forget that `\href` is actually a robust command with an optional argument (see the commented-out line):

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{#2}
% \DeclareRobustCommand*{\href}[3][]{#3}
\lstlistoflistings
\endgroup

\newpage

\lstinputlisting[
    caption = {\href{file:Marcel-1.tex}{Marcel-1.tex}},
    language = {[LaTeX]TeX}
]{Marcel-1.tex}

\end{document}
```